# can't load php modules - linux 64 bits

Tags: tidesdk

I want to use TideSDK developer with php script and follow getting start tutorial.

When i launch a basic hello script with php module, application start but the debug screen show me this message :

[Ti.Host] [Error] Could not load module (/home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libtidephp.so): "Error loading module (/home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libtidephp.so) : libgmp.so.3

I have exactly the same message for libphp5.so module.

And others php modules can't be created/launched with this message (for example) :

[Ti.Host] [Error] Could not load module (/home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libltdl.so): "Cannot load CreateModule symbol from module (/home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libltdl.so): /home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libltdl.so: undefined symbol: CreateModule

I verified all TideSDK specifics locations on my computer and everything is ok.

I'm on a Linux Mint 13 'Cinnamon' 64 bits

TideSDK 1.3.1 beta

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are missing libgmp3c2. This is a beta and we are working out a solution for ensuring the dependencies are available upon installation for linux. Most likely will be going to a .deb install for Ubuntu to ensure this as opposed to bundling more libraries in TideSDK itself. The officially supported Linux is Ubuntu but certainly interested in some broader Linux support of different flavors such as Fedora. Mint is nice with a simple and minimal UI.

Comment: The first error is resolved with an installation of libgmp3c2 but i keep the second error (for example) : [Ti.Host] [Error] Could not load module (/home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libphp5.so): "Cannot load CreateModule symbol from module (/home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libphp5.so): /home/casoars/.tidesdk/modules/linux/php/1.3.1-beta/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: CreateModule

Comment: i could not find libgmp3c2